# imagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo giving me a weird image

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I wrote some code to add a photo taken with the camera and add it to a NSMutableArray of UIImages.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    self.description.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image is %d by %d", image.size.width, image.size.height];

    //[self.imageArr addObject:image]

    //[self saveImages];
}
```

The "self.description.text" is a UILabel that I just use to get information when I test on my iPhone (my macbook is too old to upgrade to the last OS and version of Xcode).

I found that when I add the image to my imageArr, the app crashes (I know that imageArr is not nil, I've used the description UILabel to check).

If I comment out the addObject and saveImages functions, I found that, after I take a photo, the description states that the UIImage has a width of 0 and height of 1084850176. Has anyone had this problem before? I've been trying to take and save photos within the app for a few days now, and I can't seem to solve this problem.

**EDIT:**
I fixed the image dimensions problem by using %f instead of %d (thanks idz!).

It's still crashing when I uncomment the [self.imageArr addObject:image] line. The crash report says the exception type is EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) when running that line. I don't really know what this means, but I'm sure that imageArr is not nil and it is an NSMutableArray, so I don't see why it keeps crashing there.

Comment: `image.size.width` and `image.size.height` are `CGFloat`s so you should use `%f` or `%g` to print them. Also you should add more information by what you mean by crash... What message do you see?

Comment: D'oh! I fixed switched to %f and the dimensions are correct now, but it's still crashing when I uncomment the [self.imageArr addObject:image] line. The crash report says the exception type is EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) when running that line. I don't really know what this means, but I'm sure that imageArr is not nil and it is an NSMutableArray, so I don't see why it keeps crashing there.

Comment: Why do you not use NSLog to send descriptive messages to yourself??? And why do you not step thru you code in the debugger so you can see what the values of all these things really are? You are programming by *guesswork*!

Comment: can u show me the alloc init part of self.imageArr and saveImages method

Comment: @Matt - I can't debug on from my device because I'm using an outdated version of Xcode whereas my iPhone has the latest OS. I don't know a whole lot about debugging on iPhone yet, so yes I should use NSLog more and I'll take a look at that soon.

Comment: @Spynet - at the top of the the configureView function, I have `_imageArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` I also have a loadImages function I call after that that supposedly loads the images that were saved (of course none have been so far). In it I have a `NSMutableArray *tempArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` that should be filled with the loaded images and then I do `self.imageArr = [tempArr mutableCopy];` These are the only places I alloc/init the imageArr.

Comment: How to debug: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch09.html#_debugging

Comment: Normally when an SIGABRT occurs there is a lot more information about the root cause. You will have to post that information if you want people to have a chance of being able to help you out.

Comment: After playing around with the code some more, I found a way to accomplish what I am trying to do without using an array of images. I'm still curious as to why the crashes kept occurring, but I don't have the time at the moment to experiment with it more. Thank you for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have to allocate and initialize `self.imageArr`.

That's what usually causes those errors. Also if it's an array make sure it's a mutable array.